# theme path in javascript file

Tags: theme-development, themes, javascript, paths

I need to include the path to my theme file within a javascript file. How would I go about this? I have already tried:

```
var templateUrl = "<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>";

function LightboxOptions() {
  this.fileLoadingImage = "'"+templateUrl+"/img/loading.gif'";
  this.fileCloseImage = "'"+templateUrl+"/img/close.png'";
  this.resizeDuration = 700;
  this.fadeDuration = 500;
  this.labelImage = "Image";
  this.labelOf = "of";
}
```

This does not give me the path, but just inserts `<?php get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>` instead of the actual path. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are missing the `echo` ( `var templateUrl = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>";` )

Answer (score 41, accepted):

What you're looking for is [wp_localize_script function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script).

You use it like this when enqueing script

```
wp_register_script( 'my-script', 'myscript_url' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script' );
$translation_array = array( 'templateUrl' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
//after wp_enqueue_script
wp_localize_script( 'my-script', 'object_name', $translation_array );
```

In your style.js, there is going to be:

```
var templateUrl = object_name.templateUrl;
...
```

Comment: awesome. worked like a charm!

Answer (score 10):

**These are the following two ways to add theme path in javascript file.**

**1)** You can use [wp_localize_script()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) suggested by wordpress in your functions.php file. This will create a Javascript Object in the header, which will be available to your scripts at runtime.

Example :

```
wp_register_script('custom-js',get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/custom.js',array(),NULL,true);
wp_enqueue_script('custom-js');

$wnm_custom = array( 'stylesheet_directory_uri' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );
wp_localize_script( 'custom-js', 'directory_uri', $wnm_custom );
```

and can use in your js file as following :

```
alert(directory_uri.stylesheet_directory_uri);
```

**2)** You can create a Javascript snippet that saves the template directory uri in a variable, and use it later as following:
Add this code in header.php file before the js file in which you want to use this path.
Example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var stylesheet_directory_uri = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>";
</script>
```

and can use in your js file as following :

```
alert(stylesheet_directory_uri);
```

Comment: wp_localize works! I tried the 2nd approach, too, but I didn't manage to make it work. wp_localize works is probably better practice, no?

Comment: @charlenemasters to make the second approach work the order of declaring variable and accessing it is very important.

Comment: the second approach should be with `echo` in order to work

Comment: @ClaudiuCreanga Thanks, should be echo:  `var stylesheet_directory_uri = "<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>";`

Answer (score 1):

You can localize your javascript files, wich gives you the opportunity to generate a javascript array filled with PHP defined values (such as localisation or directories).

If you load your javascript file trough `wp_enqueue_script` or `wp_register_script` its easy to set up like follows:

```
function localize_vars() {
    return array(
        'stylesheet_directory' => get_stylesheet_directory_uri()
    );
}

wp_enqueue_script( 'my_script', plugins_url( 'my_plugin/my_script.js' ), array( 'jquery' ) );
wp_localize_script( 'my_script', 'my_unique_name', localize_vars() );
```

And in your javascript files, you can call these variables by:

```
my_unique_name.stylesheet_directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I started using this convenient little method to get the WordPress theme directory and store it as a global JavaScript variable (all from within a javascript file):

```
function getThemeDir() {
    var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName('script'),
        index = scripts.length - 1,
        myScript = scripts[index];

    return myScript.src.replace(/themes\/(.*?)\/(.*)/g, 'themes/$1');
}
themeDir = getThemeDir();
```

This will only work if the *following conditions* are met:

**1.** This snippet is executed via an external JavaScript file - like this:

```
<script src="/wp-content/themes/themename/assets/app.js"></script>
```

**2.** The js file resides within your site's theme directory (or subdirectory).

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it.

Place the javascript file and images in theme-folder/assets

And edit the following files.

In functions.php

```
/* for javascript (only when using child theme) */
wp_enqueue_script('my-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '-child/assets/test.js');
wp_localize_script('my-script', 'myScript', array(
    'theme_directory' => get_template_directory_uri() 
));
```

In your javascript file

```
var url = myScript.theme_directory + '-child/assets/';
```

Answer (score 0):

If the javascript file is loaded from the admin dashboard, you can use this javascript function get the root of your WordPress installation.

```
function getHomeUrl() {
  var href = window.location.href;
  var index = href.indexOf('/wp-admin');
  var homeUrl = href.substring(0, index);
  return homeUrl;
}
```

Then just contact the path to your theme like below.

```
var myThemePath = getHomeUrl() + '/wp-content/themes/myTheme';
```