# Images loaded as background-image are shown but <img>s aren't

Tags: css, directory

I got a weird problem:
First of all I provide my folder structure:

```
 wp-content/themes/theme
    ├──content.php
    ├──footer.php
    ├──functions.php
    ├──header.php
    ├──home.php
    ├──index.php
    ├──page.php
    ├──main.js
    ├──style.css
    │
    ├── media/
    │   └── img/
    │       ├── beach.mp4
    │       ├── contact-1.jpg
    │       └── offers-1.jpg
    │
    └── scripts/
        └── map.js
```

So, in my `style.css` I defined a background image like this:

```
background-image:url('media/img/offers-1.jpg');
```

That get's shown perfectly, but whatever file I load from my `index.php` (which loads `content.php`) won't get found, i.e. I got a normal image like this

```
<img src="media/img/contact-1.jpg">
```

which doesn't get found with the following error:

```
GET http://url/newer/media/img/contact-1.jpg 404 (Not Found)
```

Same for `map.js`, `main.js` and some other images.

Does anyone know what I may did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Relative paths in css files are relative to the css file location, but in PHP they are relative to the website URL not to the php file location in the server.

So to make sure you get the right URL for any resource you want to load in PHP files you can use the function [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)
like this:

`"<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>"`:

For example in `img` the attribute `src` would be:

`<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/media/img/contact-1.jpg" />`

And so on for js files and css files.

**Notice:**
In the case of using a Child theme, use this function instead [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) the same way:

`<img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/assets/img.jpg" />`

Otherwise the `get_template_directory_uri()` function in this case will only return the current **parent** theme URL and not the URL of the child theme which you are using in this case.

Comment: Or, if you're using a child theme, you should use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`

Comment: Can I add it to my answer too?

Comment: Sure, just edit your answer ;-)

Comment: Oh, didn't know that! Thanks alot! :) I managed to load `map.js` now, but it doesn't find the custom marker I set for my map (`icon: '/media/img/icons/marker.png'`). How can I add the directory in JS?

Comment: Try `icon: '../media/img/icons/marker.png'`

Comment: @Mat Didn't work :/ Don't I have to get the theme path first? Since `<?php echo get_template_directory_uri();` doesn't work in JS, it's not possible that way :/

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Javascript paths are relative to displayed page so you would need to use the full URL path. You can either hard-code this in or you can use the WP function [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) like in this answers example - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89791/theme-path-in-javascript-file

Answer (score 0):

If you are using  tag in any php file, just use [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/)

```
<img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/contact-1.jpg">
```

Comment: Thanks :) I accepted @IbrahimShendy answer tho since he explained _why_ I have to use this.